# Update MasterPage UI of Master-Details page in background tasks using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have Master Page bound with viewmodel and i want to update menu in background task when location services are on. I am able change viewmodel and see updates on UI in simulator but cannot see UI updates on real device. Viewmodel changes programmatically i can see in debug but real device not updating UI like simulator.

Please suggest me best practices if any.

Comment: try to update on main UI thread

Comment: I have created custom renderer that runs location service. What i want to do is when app detects RegionEntered than it should change Label text in hamburger menu.

Comment: You said you can see changes in emulator after you change view model. My suggestion was about that. Are you trying to describe now a new problem?

Comment: its same problem. in emulator Label text changes when i change viewmodel in renderer but same thing not working on real device.

Comment: this is very strange. if you can share the sample project I might be able to take a look and confirm.